# How to slice column with character object in data table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

How to slice column with character object in data table in R?
I have tried this piece of codes but it does not work

```
i <- "Spot"    
DT[1,i]
```

I want the code to return the result as the same as

```
DT[1,"Spot"]
```

Can I ask what is the correct way to do it with the character obejct **i** instead of the character itself "Spot"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
DT[1, ..i]
```

Or use

```
DT[1, i, with = FALSE]
```

#### data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Spot = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
```